# Is there a jQuery selector/method to find a specific parent element n levels up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

Consider the following HTML. If I have a JSON reference to the <button> element, how can I get a reference to the outer <tr> element in both cases

```
<table id="my-table">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button>Foo</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <button>Bar</button>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/js">
    $('#table button').click(function(){
        //$(this).parent().parent() will work for the first row
        //$(this).parent().parent().parent() will work for the second row
        //is there a selector or some magic json one liner that will climb
        //the DOM tree until it hits a TR, or do I have to code this myself
        //each time?            
        //$(this).????
    });
</script>
```

I know I could special case each condition, but I'm more interested "however deep you happen to be, climb the tree until you find element X"    style solution.  Something like this, but more jQuery like/less-verbose

```
var climb = function(node, str_rule){
    if($(node).is(str_rule)){
        return node;
    }
    else if($(node).is('body')){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return climb(node.parentNode, str_rule);
    }
};
```

I know about the parent(expr) method, but from what I've seen is allows you filter parents one level up and NOT climb the tree until you find expr (I'd love code example proving me wrong)

Answer (score 112, accepted):

The [parents](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) function does what you want:

```
$(this).parents("tr:first");
```

Comment: Absolutely, thanks! That's what "Edit other people's posts" permission is for ;)

Comment: Ha, that's funny.  I wondered why Visual jQuery listed parent(expr) twice; turns out I totally spaced the s at the end.

Comment: Thanks Seb, I didn't know about this at all and it's really useful. Sure beats a mess of 'parent().parent()....'

Answer (score 50):

Also, if you are using jQuery 1.3+ you can use the [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method

```
$(this).closest("tr");
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that `closest` and `parents` are very similar but have a slight difference. You can read more [here](http://api.jquery.com/closest/#entry-longdesc). Overall, I think the `closest` method is more efficient for this specific scenario.

Comment: hmm, very easy to understand this function name.

Answer (score 0):

not jQuery but this options works much better

node.contains( otherNode )

> The Node.contains() method returns a Boolean value indicating whether
>   a node is a descendant of a given node or not

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/contains