# Get id value if click on span element inside

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

It is possible with jQuery to get value of ID of `pop-up-custom` which is `ideation` if user click on `<span>` element which is nested inside `pop-up-custom` class ?

```
<div class="elementor-element pop-up-custom" id="ideation" data-widget_type="eael-lightbox.default">
<div class="elementor-widget-container">
                
<div data-lightbox-type="lightbox_type_custom_html" data-lightbox-type-url="" data-lightbox-trigger-pageload="1" data-lightbox-closebtn-color="#ffffff" class="eael-lightbox-wrapper" data-trigger="eael_lightbox_trigger_button" data-lightbox-id="lightbox_639c25cc43a03" data-type="inline" data-src="#eael-lightbox-window-639c25cc43a03" data-popup-layout="eael-lightbox-popup-standard" data-main-class="eael-lightbox-modal-popup-cf4e9a1" data-close_button="yes" data-esc_exit="yes" data-click_exit="yes" data-effect="animated " data-trigger-element=".eael-modal-popup-link-639c25cc43a03">
<div class="eael-lightbox-btn">
<span id="btn-eael-lightbox-639c25cc43a03" class="eael-modal-popup-button eael-modal-popup-link eael-modal-popup-link-639c25cc43a03 elementor-button elementor-size-md">Request</span></div><!-- close .eael-lightbox-btn -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Reason why I am asking for such logic is because code is getting generated by buider and I have access to change the id and class of top element, So ultimately goal is to when user click on `<span>` then I want to grab the id of top element.

```
jQuery(".pop-up-custom > span").click(function() {
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

Comment: `>` is **direct** [child selector](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/). Your `<span>` element is **not** a direct child of  `.pop-up-custom`. Indent your code properly and this might become clearer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JQuery: Get the parent element id of a clicked element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922032/jquery-get-the-parent-element-id-of-a-clicked-element)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699027/is-there-a-jquery-selector-method-to-find-a-specific-parent-element-n-levels-up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can covert `this` into a jQuery object using `$(this)` so that you can then call the [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method which will traverse up the span's elements to find the element with `pop-up-custom` class. You can then grab its id using `attr('id')`. See example below:

```js
jQuery(".pop-up-custom span").click(function() {
  console.log($(this).closest(".pop-up-custom").attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="elementor-element pop-up-custom" id="ideation" data-widget_type="eael-lightbox.default">
  <div class="elementor-widget-container">
    <div data-lightbox-type="lightbox_type_custom_html" data-lightbox-type-url="" data-lightbox-trigger-pageload="1" data-lightbox-closebtn-color="#ffffff" class="eael-lightbox-wrapper" data-trigger="eael_lightbox_trigger_button" data-lightbox-id="lightbox_639c25cc43a03"
      data-type="inline" data-src="#eael-lightbox-window-639c25cc43a03" data-popup-layout="eael-lightbox-popup-standard" data-main-class="eael-lightbox-modal-popup-cf4e9a1" data-close_button="yes" data-esc_exit="yes" data-click_exit="yes" data-effect="animated "
      data-trigger-element=".eael-modal-popup-link-639c25cc43a03">
      <div class="eael-lightbox-btn">
        <span id="btn-eael-lightbox-639c25cc43a03" class="eael-modal-popup-button eael-modal-popup-link eael-modal-popup-link-639c25cc43a03 elementor-button elementor-size-md">Request</span>
      </div> <!-- close .eael-lightbox-btn -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am still facing an issue, while having multiple codes with same button with different ID's , it 's selecting the first one.

Comment: Can you give an example of the HTML? @SanadCal

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".pop-up-custom span").click(function() {
  console.log($(this).parents('.pop-up-custom').attr('id'));
});
```

```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="elementor-element pop-up-custom" id="ideation" data-widget_type="eael-lightbox.default">
  <div class="elementor-widget-container">
    <div data-lightbox-type="lightbox_type_custom_html" data-lightbox-type-url="" data-lightbox-trigger-pageload="1" data-lightbox-closebtn-color="#ffffff" class="eael-lightbox-wrapper" data-trigger="eael_lightbox_trigger_button" data-lightbox-id="lightbox_639c25cc43a03" data-type="inline" data-src="#eael-lightbox-window-639c25cc43a03" data-popup-layout="eael-lightbox-popup-standard" data-main-class="eael-lightbox-modal-popup-cf4e9a1" data-close_button="yes" data-esc_exit="yes" data-click_exit="yes" data-effect="animated " data-trigger-element=".eael-modal-popup-link-639c25cc43a03">
     <div class="eael-lightbox-btn">
        <span id="btn-eael-lightbox-639c25cc43a03" class="eael-modal-popup-button eael-modal-popup-link eael-modal-popup-link-639c25cc43a03 elementor-button elementor-size-md">Request
        </span>
     </div><!-- close .eael-lightbox-btn -->
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```